# OSGi capabilities: effective time: resolve vs active

Tags: java, osgi, bnd

When should a capability have an effective time "resolve" and when "active"?

When do you want capabilities to be ignored while resolving a resource? When do you want them to be respected?

http://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/230-manifest-annotations.html

https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/e4ffaf6e5fa404972c11e8ff20f3a1228b1655a9/biz.aQute.bndlib/src/aQute/bnd/annotation/headers/RequireCapability.java

https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/core/org/osgi/resource/Namespace.html#EFFECTIVE_ACTIVE

Comment: This does not sound like a question for stackoverflow as it is largely discussion

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not easy, I think you can get the necessary information from the OSGi core specification.

See chapter *3.3.3 Bundle Capabilities*

> effective - (resolve) Specifies the time a capability is available, either resolve (default) or another name. The OSGi framework resolver only considers Capabilities without an effective directive or effective:=resolve. Capabilities with other values for the effective directive can be considered by an external agent.

I think the important part here is the "**considered by an external agent**".

You can find the same in chapter *3.3.6 Bundle Requirements*

> effective - (resolve) Specifies the time a requirement is considered, either resolve (default) or another name. The OSGi framework resolver only considers requirements without an effective directive or effective:=resolve. **Other requirements can be considered by an external agent**. Additional names for the effective directive should be registered with the OSGi Alliance

In short: Only *effective:=resolve (default)* is processed by the OSGi container. Other values might be processed by 3rdparty technologies.

In chapter *8.6 osgi.identity Namespace* you can find an example about non-resolve effectiveness:

```
Require-Capability: «
  osgi.identity; «
  filter:="(&(osgi.identity=org.example.foo-source)(version=1.1))"; «
  effective:=meta; «
  classifier:=sources; «
  resolution:=optional
```

**I guess** this requirement coud be resolved by development environments. By resolving this requirement the source of the bundle can be downloaded from an external repository.

*effective:=active* can be useful if you want to mention OSGi service usage in the MANIFEST headers. These requirements are not processed by the OSGi container, but it is good to know that bundle XY needs an OSGi service to be able to start its functionality (by checking the requirements of the bundle).

Comment: Hmm, this would mean that the examples at http://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/230-manifest-annotations.html don't show what you would usually use, since they are all specifying `effective="active"`